# Installing Google Cloud SDK throwing error in install.py when using install.bat

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to install google cloud SDK using install.bat. I have tried downloading the bundled pythons versions 275 and current version 276, they both fail at the same spot. It is able to find python in the platform/bundledpython folder so that is not the issue. I have also tried the suggestions online including making sure that the "Find" command works on a command prompt. Any help appreciated.

```
The latest available version is: 276.0.0

���───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐Trac
back (most recent call last):
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 225, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 203, in main
    Install(pargs.override_components, pargs.additional_components)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 148, in Install
    _CLI.Execute(['--quiet', 'components', 'list'])
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 1007, in Execute
    self._HandleAllErrors(exc, command_path_string, specified_arg_names)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 1040, in _HandleAllErrors
    exceptions.HandleError(exc, command_path_string, self.__known_error_handler)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\exceptions.py", line 527, in HandleError
    core_exceptions.reraise(exc)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\exceptions.py", line 146, in reraise
    six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 981, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 809, in Run
    display_info=self.ai.display_info).Display()
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\display.py", line 483, in Display
    self._printer.Print(self._resources)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\resource\resource_printer_base.py", line 279, in P
int
    self.Finish()
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\resource\table_printer.py", line 467, in Finish
    self._out.write(line)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\log.py", line 239, in write
    self._Write(plain_text, styled_text)
  File "C:\google-cloud-sdk\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\log.py", line 232, in _Write
    self.__stream_wrapper.stream.write(stream_msg)
```

Comment: Is that the entire stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem trying to install the latest Google Cloud SDK (276.0.0). The Windows setup was stuck on "Installing components".

[image]

Looking at the process list with *Process Explorer* I could see it was running this command that was stuck, as you probably did to get your stack trace. I took the command line and ran it in a separate Administror cmd.exe (paths might differ per system, the idea is the same).

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK"
SET "CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1"
SET "CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=%APPDATA%\gcloud"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\install.bat" --quiet --disable-installation-options --path-update "FALSE" --usage-reporting "true" --additional-components beta powershell"
```

Running them would produce the same error / stack trace.

Editing `log.py` and commenting out (prefix with #) line 232 would make it get further, but it runs into a separate problem:

```
ERROR: Cannot use bundled Python installation to update Cloud SDK in non-interactive mode. 
Please run again in interactive mode.
```

Enable prompts with `CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS` envvar and remove `--quiet` and `--disable-installation-options` from the `install.bat` command line and run it again.

```
SET "CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=0"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\install.bat" --path-update "FALSE" --usage-reporting "true" --additional-components beta powershell"
```

This time it should continue, start a new console where it actually installs the components and eventually finish succesfully.